# What is the market for small liquid rocket motors (0.5 to 10 kN thrust)?

Tags: rockets, commercial, liquid-fuel

I was wondering if anyone had information on the availability of small liquid fuelled rocket motors in the US (or elsewhere)

Comment: This is basically a product recommendation question, and these are [generally frowned upon throughout the Stack Exchange network](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for reasons mentioned in the link. Please follow guidelines there to make this an acceptable question for us. Otherwise, answers will basically amount to personal preferences that might or mightn't apply to your use case in incomplete and possibly biased lists that won't age well. Thanks!

Comment: @TildalWave While I agree that being a bit more specific would help with answering the question, I don't think it's fair to say that he's asking for a product recommendation. He's asking what companies manufacture these. Also, most of the arguments why product recommendation questions are bad do not apply to SE. Most of these thrusters were designed decades ago with minor upgrades (so why will they be obsolete next year?), personal preference is not much of an issue, prices are unavailable in any case, and he explained that he wanted US manufacturers first.

Answer (score 2):

Moog offers several such thrusters:

http://www.moog.com/products/thrusters/apogee-upper-stage-thrusters/

Rocketdyne has an entire range of thrusters as well:

https://www.rocket.com/propulsion-systems/bipropellant-rockets

In Europe, there is always airbus:

http://cs.astrium.eads.net/sp/spacecraft-propulsion/bipropellant-thrusters/index.html
http://cs.astrium.eads.net/sp/spacecraft-propulsion/hydrazine-thrusters/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a very strange question as far as strange questions come, so let me answer is straight away; I have not found any resource online that sells liquid fuelled rocket motors.

Now even if I had, the legality of a 500-10,000 Newton rocket motor is very shaky. According to the [FAA Code of Federal Regulations](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:2.0.1.3.15#sp14.2.101.c) (paraphrased):

```
If the rocket & payload (including fuel) weighs more than 3.3 lbs...

If the rocket has more than 125 grams of fuel...

If a single motor rocket has more than 160 N-sec of impulse...

If multiple stages add up to more than 320 N-sec of impulse...

If the average thrust is more than 80 N...
```

... you will need a waiver from the FAA to launch the rocket.

Any rocket exceeding these parameters is subject to approval on the FAA's discretion. There are a host of other complications like proximity to population and airports.

To conclude; there are [far better](https://www.estesrockets.com) (safer) propulsion systems than liquid fuel motors.

Comment: I think op's question was aimed towards the commercial side of things and not amateur rocketry. Maybe they could be used as an apogee kick motor or for attitude control on large spacecraft, though I could be guessing.

Comment: Not better if you want good performance or the ability to turn off.